# Actualizar campos parciales con Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Estoy manejando un proyecto con `MVC` y `EF 6.2`, en mi modelo tengo una entidad que presenta cuatro campos:

```
public class Entidad
{
  public string campo1 {get; set;}
  public string campo2 {get; set;}
  public string campo3 {get; set;}
  public string campo4 {get; set;}
}
```

Mi clase de `DAO` tiene el método de actualización de la siguiente forma:

```
public void actualizar(Entidad entidad)
{
  using(var context = new DbContext())
  {
    context.Entry(entidad).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

Sin embargo cuando al método actualizar le paso como parámetro una entidad con cuatro campos seteados (**campo1, campo2, campo3 y campo4**), el registro de la base de datos se actualiza de forma correcta, sin embargo si paso una entidad solo con tres o dos campos seteados (ej: **campo1 y campo3** con sus nuevos valores) el registro no se actualiza.

¿Debo obtener la entidad de la `BD` y comparar campo por campo si es diferente e ir actualizándolo y después si hacer la actualización?

Comment: Me parece que es EntityState.Modified, no Entity.State.Modified  como lo tienes puesto. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Podes hacerlo determinando cuales son los campos que necesitas que sean modificados

**Por ejemplo**

```
public void actualizar(Entidad entidad)
{
  using (var context = new DBContext())
  {
    context.Entry.Attach(entidad);
    context.Entry(entidad).Property(x => x.campo1).IsModified = true;
    db.SaveChanges();

//En este caso, sólo campo1 se modificaría en la base de datos.

  }
}
```

Espero que haya sido lo que andabas buscando, saludos!

Comment: Juan Salvador, muchas gracias, de acuerdo a lo que he visto es requerido saber con exactitud cuales son los campos que se modifican, no existe una merge que tome la entidad original y solo le actualice los campos modificados. Como estoy usuando una Unidad de Trabajo, en capa de negocio consulto la entidad, actualizo los datos que requiero y envio la entidad modificada.